# onPostExecute() gets called without completing task in doInBackground()

Tags: android

This is my code for recording video and saving it to drive. But my logs show the following :

```
03-09 08:43:55.005 12760-12760/classroom.shivani.upload I/drive-quickstart: API client connected.
03-09 08:43:55.005 12760-12760/classroom.shivani.upload I/drive-quickstart: Starting camera Intent
03-09 08:43:55.014 12760-12760/classroom.shivani.upload I/drive-quickstart: file uri is :file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/VID_20170309_084355.mp4
03-09 08:43:55.052 12760-12760/classroom.shivani.upload I/drive-quickstart: calling rccv
03-09 08:43:55.053 12760-12760/classroom.shivani.upload I/drive-quickstart: In pre execute
03-09 08:43:55.057 12760-13801/classroom.shivani.upload I/drive-quickstart: In background
03-09 08:43:55.058 12760-13801/classroom.shivani.upload I/drive-quickstart: file path is :/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/VID_20170309_084355.mp4
03-09 08:43:55.058 12760-13801/classroom.shivani.upload I/drive-quickstart: file name is :VID_20170309_084355.mp4
03-09 08:43:55.175 12760-12760/classroom.shivani.upload I/drive-quickstart: In post execute
```

What should I do to save video to drive ?

```
private class Async extends AsyncTask<File,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.i(TAG, "In pre execute");
        }
    protected Void doInBackground(File... params)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "In background");
                final File file1=params[0];

                Log.i(TAG, "file path is :"+file1.getPath());
                Log.i(TAG, "file name is :"+file1.getName());

                Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                            return;
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");
                        OutputStream outputStream =
                                result.getDriveContents()
                                        .getOutputStream();
                        FileInputStream fis;
                        try {

                            Log.i(TAG, "Within try catch");

                            fis = new FileInputStream(file1.getPath
                                    ());
                            Log.i(TAG, "file name is :"+file1.getName());
                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new
                                    ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            byte[] buf = new byte[102400];
                            int n;
                            while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
                                baos.write(buf, 0, n);
                            byte[] photoBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                            outputStream.write(photoBytes);

                            outputStream.close();

                            fis.close();
                            Log.i(TAG, "successfully created video file");
                            Log.i(TAG, "Setting Metadata");
                            String title = file1.getName();
                            MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet =
                                    new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                            .setMimeType("video/mp4").setTitle
                                            (title).build();

                            Log.i(TAG, "Creating new video on Drive (" + title
                                    + ")");
                            IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                                    .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                                    .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                                    .setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
                                    .build(mGoogleApiClient);
                            try {
                                startIntentSenderForResult(
                                        intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
                            }


                            Log.i(TAG, "congrats new video created with name (" + title + ")");

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "FileNotFoundException: "
                                    + e.getMessage());
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to write file contents." + e1.getMessage());
                        }
                        // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.


                    }
                });
            return null;
            }

 protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.i(TAG, "In post execute");


        }
```

I am creating instance of Async class as:

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting camera Intent");
        String mediaStorageDir= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath();
        String timeStamp=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(mediaStorageDir + java.io.File.separator +"VID_"+timeStamp + ".mp4"));
        file=new File(fileUri.getPath());
        Log.i(TAG, "file uri is :"+fileUri);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,15);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,fileUri);
        startActivity(cameraIntent);
        Log.i(TAG, "calling rccv");
        new Async().execute(file);

    }
```

Comment: Just do away with the asynctask and just call the code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this

```
protected Void doInBackground(File... params) {

    Log.i(TAG, "In background");
    final File file1=params[0];

    Log.i(TAG, "file path is :"+file1.getPath());
    Log.i(TAG, "file name is :"+file1.getName());

    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
        // all the other stuff
    });

    return null;
}
```

you are essentially blowing straight through the  `doInBackground()` and returning null straight away, as the method will not wait for the DriveApi to do whatever it is doing. This is not how an Async task should be used.

Just try calling this on the main thread, its more than likely already an async task or something similar

```
Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
    // all the other stuff
});
```

Comment: will you please elaborate

Comment: `setResultCallback()`. You are setting a callback. But the callback is not executed directly. Only much later. But newDriveContents returns immediately. And hence your doInBackground finishes and your onPostExecute is called. After that -much later- the callback is invoked.

Comment: So what is solution for that?

Comment: @ShivaniDegloorkar i don't know much about `Drive.DriveApi` but just try running it on the main thread, `newDriveContents` more than likely already executes as an async task

Comment: @JoeMaher i  had tried doing so earlier. Actually my whole code was running on main thread . But earlier too it was problematic. some videos got uploaded while some didnt .

Answer (score 0):

I solved a very similar problem by declaring both doInBackground and onPostExecute synchronized.
 
(...)
protected **synchronized** void doInBackground(Void... params)
{...}
 
protected **synchronized** void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {...}
(...)
In my case, doInBackground() was entering first (as it should) but somehow onPostExecute() was called before doInBackground() "technically" completed (I couldnt figure out why - maybe my unzip library objects had its own threads and did not block the doInBackground() method). Synchronizing the methods solved the problem (not without performance consequences, of course)